# mingw gcc compiler is giving an error which i m unable to understand, when i m trying to print 1- 10 numbers using recursion

Tags: c, gcc

the following error shows ,when i try to compile the source code

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-7.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev2/mingw32/bin/.
./lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot
 open output file print.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the code of my program is given below

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print(int x)
 {
  if(x==1)
  {
   printf("%d\n", x);
   return;
  }
 else
{
 print(x-1);
 printf("%d\n",x);
}
}
 void main()
{
print(10);
}
```

it is working fine in Turbo C.
what kind of error it is ? how can I correct it?

Comment: It is not allowed to write `print.exe` in the *current folder*. Presumably you should try to compile the code in a folder that would be writable...

Comment: Make sure your virus checker isn't blocking it.

Comment: One of many reasons to avoid recursion is that it tends to become an unreadable mess. Did you realize that your function could be written much more readable, as `void print(int x)
{ if(x!=1)
  {
    print(x-1);
  }
  printf("%d\n",x);
}`. Of course in either case, there won't be tail recursion so the only thing achieved was to write the equivalent to a plain loop, but in a horribly inefficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to kill the existing process that is running. kill the `print.exe` process an it will be accessible or simply close the `command prompt window` which opened the execution instance.

Comment: Not sure it's that here - that code will run in the blink of an eye, even when compiled with turbo C !

Comment: @Bathsheba.: But I have got this error so many times for the same reason I posted....I did this and it wokred,

Comment: @Bathsheba.: What you have said is right...but for tha t it wont show...`open output file print.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: I'll upvote in good faith; nobody has demonstrated that this is not correct.

Comment: @Bathsheba.: But really they ask the question then don't stay for even sometime to verify the answer. Most of the time this is the solution.